# Leverage browser caching - Internal Server Error when modifying .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-expires

I'm trying to speed my site. On google PageSpeed Insights I have 86 point but I have problem with `Leverage browser caching`. In recomendation I found this piece of `.htaccess` code:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But when I insert it to my `.htaccess` file I get Internal Server Error (500).

My working `.htaccess` code loks like that:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php53 .php 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php

# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4         gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE             !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: can your check your Apache error.log and see what the error is?

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't - that is not my server

Comment: Its funny that you want to fix "an error" but what that error is you can't find out.

Comment: I can find out, but tomorrow - I have to wait for administrator

Comment: Meanwhile try commenting out `AddHandler x-httpd-php53 .php` line and see if this helps.

Comment: It have to be there - it "connecting" me to php 5.3

Comment: Shouldn't that be via `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in Apache config?

Comment: What does this have to do with Leverage browser caching?

Comment: I thought you're getting `Internal Server Error (500)` :P

Comment: yes, but only with `ExpiresActive On...`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should enable module "mod_expires" on the server: 
using ubuntu server type:

a2enmod expires

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart